# Searching 'TODO' is not working in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, todo

TODO is not working in PyCharm. When I comment out and use TODO, there is no any highlight and PyCharm also found 0 TODO items.

And I also create a new project but the result is same. Here is what I did:

[image: screenshot Here is what I did]

---

**Edit:**

Someone advised me to check the TODO setting, but mine is fine. My PyCharm setting:

[image: screenshot My PyCharm setting]

---

**First add:**

Somehow it worked. I did nothing, but it worked.

But there is one more question for me. I mark a directory as exclusion. And in there TODO still does not work. Is it normal or get a new hitch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure default TODO patterns are in place:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.But there is one more question for me.Could you please help me out?

Comment: It's an expected behavior. To find all todos PyCharm has to index the code base and excluded directories aren't analyzed by the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Mine started working after I ran "git add ."